# Remote gdb stops at every event

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, gdbserver

I'm having remote ARM Linux box which I need to debug.

The server is started:

```
gdbserver :12345 ./my_app
```

The client:

```
./arm-am3354-linux-gnueabihf-gdb ~/
 (gdb) target remote dev_r:12345
 (gdb) continue
```

Then I'm trying to pause the app with Ctrl+C, but the gdb stops with:

> [Inferior 1 (process 2766) exited with code 01]

And on server:

> Child exited with status 1 
>   GDBserver exiting

Story:
I was trying to use remote debugging in QtCreator, but when setting breakpoints in run-time the gdb was crashing in the same way. Also the breakpoints and pause is not working in QtCreator.
I was trying also another gdb like gdb-multiarch and the one from android-sdk.

Update:
Debugging small program aka Hello World works. Local Debugging (on x86) works too. The app itself has hundred thousand lines of code, shared and static libraries.

Partial solution:
Probably the sysroot for embedded platform that I've got was invalid. After copying /lib/ and /usr/ from the target device and setting it as

```
set sysroot /home/karel/sysroot
```

I'm able to set breakpoints and the app stops at them. The pause however is still stopping the remote app. The same for QtCreator: Tools->Options->Debugger->GDB->Additional Attach Commands

Comment: What device do you need? http://www.ironlab.io allows debugging on real devices in the cloud. They are in free beta now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (or even exactly the same?) issue with debugging my application running on the EGLFS platform. Debugging when built with Qt 5.4 was working perfectly fine, debugging with Qt 5.5 did behave as you describe.

After hours of searching, I found that my application on Qt 5.5 exited when receiving a SIGINT, whereas on Qt 5.4, the debugger could pause the application as expected. Since GDB sends SIGINT when trying to pause the application or setting / removing a breakpoint, this was where trouble started.

After some more research, I finally found the following commit to Qt 5.5: [Fix up signal handling in QFbVtHandler](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/commit/src/platformsupport/fbconvenience/qfbvthandler.cpp?h=v5.5.0&id=f6e6ef46b382e1a7f827afc5f70ce6e5deaa7e86). At the very end, you see that when receiving SIGINT or SIGTERM, the `handleInt()` handler is called where we finally run into `_exit(1)`. Setting a breakpoint there confirmed that this is exactly what happens when trying to pause or set a breakpoint with GDB.

**Solution that worked for me**: I have created a patch to qfbvthandler.cpp, simply removing the `#define VTH_ENABLED` line.

GDB debugging is now again working like a charm.

Note: Even though qfbvthandler.cpp has been updated in Qt5.6 and upwards, I suspect the behaviour would still be the same. I however don't have a workspace set up in order to test this.